# How to test email headers using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec-rails, sendgrid

I'm using SendGrid's [SMTP API](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/smtp-api/) in my Rails application to send out emails. However, I'm running into troubles testing the email header ("X-SMTPAPI") using RSpec.

Here's what the email looks like (retrieving from ActionMailer::Base.deliveries):

```
#<Mail::Message:2189335760, Multipart: false, Headers: 
<Date: Tue, 20 Dec 2011 16:14:25 +0800>, 
<From: "Acme Inc" <contact@acmeinc.com>>, 
<To: doesntmatter@nowhere.com>, 
<Message-ID: <4ef043e1b9490_4e4800eb1b095f1@Macbook.local.mail>>, 
<Subject: Your Acme order>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, 
<Content-Type: text/plain>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>, 
<X-SMTPAPI: {"sub":{"|last_name|":[Foo],"|first_name|":[Bar]},"to":["foo@bar.com"]}>>
```

Here's my spec code (which failed):

```
ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to.should include("foo@bar.com")
```

I've also tried various method to retrieve the header("X-SMTPAPI") and didn't work either:

```
mail = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
mail.headers("X-SMTPAPI") #NoMethodError: undefined method `each_pair' for "X-SMTPAPI":String
```

Help?

## Update (answer)

Turns out, I can do this to retrieve the value of the email header:

```
mail.header['X-SMTPAPI'].value
```

However, the returned value is in JSON format. Then, all I need to do is to decode it:

```
sendgrid_header = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(mail.header['X-SMTPAPI'].value)
```

which returns a hash, where I can do this:

```
sendgrid_header["to"]
```

to retrieve the array of email addresses.

Answer (score 12):

The email_spec gem has a bunch of matchers that make this easier, you can do stuff like

```
mail.should have_header('X-SMTPAPI', some_value)
mail.should deliver_to('foo@bar.com')
```

And perusing the source to that gem should point you in the right direction if you don't want to use it e.g.

```
mail.to.addrs
```

returns you the email addresses (as opposed to stuff like 'Bob ')

and

```
mail.header['foo']
```

gets you the field for the foo header (depending on what you're checking you may want to call `to_s` on it to get the actual field value)

Comment: Thanks. I've checked out email_spec gem. The "deliver_to" matcher is similar to the "to" matcher (which returns "doesntmatter@nowhere.com" instead of "foo@bar.com") and the "have_header" matcher simply returns the full header. Anyway, I've found out a solution to this and will post it up now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Repeating some of the other advice here, in more modern rspec syntax:

```
RSpec.describe ImportFile::Mailer do
  describe '.file_error' do
    let(:mail) { described_class.file_error('daily.csv', 'missing header') }

    it { expect(mail.subject).to eq("Import error: missing header in daily.csv") }
    it { expect(mail.header['X-source-file'].to_s).to eq ('daily.csv') }
  end
end
```